# Incorrect Looping causing excessive records when Should be less

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I know for a fact that I have only 54858 items in a table of mine that I am bringing over to a phone but for some reason, its managed to get passed this. Its got to 13600 so something must be wrong in my logic.

I am using realm.io to store my data on the phone locally. Also, how does one best dertimn the batch size because I won't no the amount of records all the time I cant just set /1000 because for the above that just gives me back 548 which is not correct to set the progress bar by.

```
int count = await restServices.GetStockTakeAllCountForWarehouse(warehouseId);
```

This returns the correct amount of records 54858

```
int batchsize = 1000;   
int localCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i += batchsize)
{
   localCount += i;
   lblCount.Text = $"Transefering Stock Count Sheet { localCount.ToString()}";
   if (i >= count)
   {
     await DisplayAlert("Test", "Download of Stock Sheet Count complete", "OK");
     return;
    }
    results = await restServices.GetStockTakeAllWithPagging(warehouseId, i, batchsize);
    foreach (var items in results)
    {  realm.Write(() =>
       {
          realm.Add(new RealmStockTakeItems { BinName = items.BinName, ItemCode = items.Code, Description = items.Name, BarCode = items.Barcode, UOM = items.StockUnitName, StocktakeCountShtItemID = items.StocktakeCountShtItemID, RecordedQuantityInStock =(int) items.RecordedQuantityInStock, ActualQuantityEntered = items.ActualQuantityEntered, ActualQuantityInStock = (int)items.ActualQuantityInStock });
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: The count is basically an api call which simply retrieves the number of total records this is verified and correct.step count is not being used

Comment: the statement `if (i >= count)` inside the loop that defines that `i < count`, can that really happen? When does the lambda of realm.Write execute? Seeing the implementation (even if it's just a simple overview of how the paging works and what the parameters really are) would be handy to have, what happens if you just aggregate all the results in your first for, and then write that aggregated list outside of the loop?

Comment: simply printing out the values of all your counters, as well as the actual count of items returned by `GetStockTakeAllWithPagging` should tell you what's going on

Comment: "54858 items in a table ... its managed to get passed this. Its got to 13600".  13,600 is less than 54,858